# $exception {Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.} System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

I created a method to edit the WindowsForm control property like the text for the textbox.
but I create this method in a different class ( not Form1 Class), this method will be called by button click handler like in below:
but I am getting [exception {Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until ]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Update_UI Update_UI = new Update_UI();

            if (_client!=null )
            {
                _trigger = false;
                _StatusTxtBox.InvokeEx(stb => stb.Text += CRLF + " Server Disconnecting....");
                _client.Close();
                _listener.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                Update_UI.UpdateUI("Update 02");
                //UpdateUI("Update_01");
            }
                
        }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Server_app
{
   public class Update_UI
    {
        // To populate String:
        public void UpdateUI(string s)
        {
            
           Form1 f = new Form1();
            Func<int> fn = delegate ()
            {
              f._StatusTxtBox.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine + s);
                return 0;
            };
            
                
                f._StatusTxtBox.Invoke(fn);

            
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks,
Elsayed

Comment: Just double checking here, but you understand that `UpdateUI` is creating a new `Form1` each time you call it, right? It's not actioning changes on an existing `Form1`

Comment: I didn’t intend to create a new Form i just i want to access the current Form, so I think here is the problem, so how can i access the current Form elements from an external class like here.

Comment: You need to pass a reference to it.

Comment: Thank you I did as you told me and I passed the Form1 by reference like start working as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I did that in my code to pass Form1 as ref Parameter to an external class
but how can I pass another windowsform as ref to this class

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f = this as Form1;
        Update_UI_Frm1 Update_UI = new Update_UI_Frm1();

        if (_client!=null )
        {
            _trigger = false;
            _StatusTxtBox.InvokeEx(stb => stb.Text += CRLF + " Server is Disconnecting....");
            _client.Close();
            _listener.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
           
            Update_UI.UpdateUIFrm1(ref f,"Update 02");
            
        }
            
    }

public class Update_UI_Frm1
{
    // To populate String:
    public void UpdateUIFrm1(ref Form1 refform,string s)
    {
        Form1 Frm1 = refform;
        Func<int> fn = delegate ()
        {
          Frm1._StatusTxtBox.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine + s);
            return 0;
        };
            Frm1._StatusTxtBox.Invoke(fn);
        
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please any Idea how can i pass several windows form by reference to specific class